# The things inside the for loop don't work

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

The theme is Minecraft.

From my coding paper it reads (with edits from me):

"A player's inventory of tools is given in a list.

```
current_inventory=["wooden pickaxe", "iron sword", "wooden pickaxe", "wooden sword", "wooden axe", "stone axe", "stone pickaxe", "wooden sword", "iron sword", "wooden pickaxe", "stone sword"]
```

The player's toolbelt does not have space to carry that many tools, drop four duplicate items from the inventory into a chest.

[Here is the actual thing](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19tclaZLAdjjhYc7lo-ni7VjBnaoPzDVP#scrollTo=YIRFbbyYQLyF) (only view).

And this is the code:

```
current_inventory=["wooden pickaxe", "iron sword", "wooden pickaxe", "wooden sword", "wooden axe", "stone axe", "stone pickaxe", "wooden sword", "iron sword", "wooden pickaxe", "stone sword"]

chest = []

for i in current_inventory:

    if i in current_inventory:

        current_inventory.remove(i)

        chest.append(i)

        print(f"Depositing {i} into the chest")

print("The chest has:")

for x in chest:

    print(x)

print("Your inventory has:")

for y in current_inventory:

    print(y)

print("Locking chest...")
```

**Expected:**

Depositing wooden pickaxe into the chest

Depositing wooden pickaxe into the chest

Depositing wooden sword into the chest

Depositing iron sword into the chest

The chest has:

wooden pickaxe

wooden pickaxe

wooden sword

iron sword

Your inventory has:

wooden pickaxe

stone axe

wooden sword

iron sword

wooden axe

stone sword

Locking chest...

**Actual:**

Depositing wooden pickaxe into the chest

Depositing wooden pickaxe into the chest

Depositing wooden axe into the chest

Depositing stone pickaxe into the chest

Depositing iron sword into the chest

Depositing stone sword into the chest

The chest has:

wooden pickaxe

wooden pickaxe

wooden axe

stone pickaxe

iron sword

stone sword

Your inventory has:

wooden sword

stone axe

wooden sword

iron sword

wooden pickaxe

Locking chest...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please revise your question title to ask an actual, specific question that describes the problem. (I'm actually surprised that the system allowed that generic one.)

Comment: We do not have access to google drive file, please add permission to it.

Comment: "This code doesn't work the way I want it to" < Please fix this. If everyone named their question this, StackOverflow would be pointless!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are looping over `i` in `current_inventory`, the inner condition `if i in current_inventory` will always be true. Modify your code to only act on duplicate items.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer

```
current_inventory=["wooden pickaxe", "iron sword", "wooden pickaxe", "wooden sword", "wooden axe", "stone axe", "stone pickaxe", "wooden sword", "iron sword", "wooden pickaxe", "stone sword"]
chest = []
copy_inventory = current_inventory.copy()
for i in current_inventory:
    copy_inventory.remove(i)
    if i in copy_inventory:
        chest.append(i)
        print(f"Depositing {i} into the chest")
    else:
        print(f'keeping {i} in inventory')
        copy_inventory.append(i)
print("The chest has:")
for x in chest:
    print(x)
print("Your inventory has:")
for y in copy_inventory:
    print(y)
print("Locking chest...")
```

Which outputs:

Depositing wooden pickaxe into the chest

Depositing iron sword into the chest

Depositing wooden pickaxe into the chest

Depositing wooden sword into the chest

keeping wooden axe in inventory

keeping stone axe in inventory

keeping stone pickaxe in inventory

keeping wooden sword in inventory

keeping iron sword in inventory

keeping wooden pickaxe in inventory

keeping stone sword in inventory

The chest has:

wooden pickaxe

iron sword

wooden pickaxe

wooden sword

Your inventory has:

wooden axe

stone axe

stone pickaxe

wooden sword

iron sword

wooden pickaxe

stone sword

Locking chest...